# Parse Javascript Object to JSON-like string, but with single quotes

Tags: javascript, parsing, stringify

This is my Javascript object that I converted into a string (JSON)

```js
var myObj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    group: 'O+'
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

I need the output with single quotes (apostrophes) (') and not double quotes ("). Also no quotes or apostrophes on the indexes/keys. I want it to look like this:

```
{name:'John',age:25,group:'O+'}
```

I tried this:

```js
var myObj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    group: 'O+'
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '$1:'));
```

This removes the quotes on the indexes/keys but the values still have quotes in them. Need to replace them with apostrophes. Tried some more regexes but they did not work.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you need to print it in this specific way. It's an object and it is not made for printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add some more replaces at the end of that stringify, you can actually get what you want. Here is your example:

```js
var myObj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    group: 'O+'
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '$1:').replace(/\\"/g, '"')
    .replace(/([\{|:|,])(?:[\s]*)(")/g, "$1'")
    .replace(/(?:[\s]*)(?:")([\}|,|:])/g, "'$1")
    .replace(/([^\{|:|,])(?:')([^\}|,|:])/g, "$1\\'$2"));
```

You can find this exact example on a different forum on stackexchange. Here is the [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69266/json-conversion-to-single-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse reviver` to format the values like this.

```js
var myObj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    group: 'O+',
    bool:true,
    hello:{
        a:'bb'
    }
}
const reviver =(key, value)=>{
if(typeof value === 'string'){
  return `'${value}'`
}
return value
}
var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj), reviver);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a).replace(/"/g,''));
```

Comment: This changes the field type of age.